# Iterating over a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to come up with a better solution but no luck so far. 
I have a dictionary:

```
dict = {"a":(1,2,3),"b":(4,5,6)}
```

I need to iterate it through a class:

```
class App(object):
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x

    def key(self,key):
        print key

    def value1(self,value1):
        print value1

    def value2(self,value2):
        print value2

    def value3(self,value3):
        print value3
```

A solution I have so far is:

```
app = App(0)
while app.x < len(dict.keys()):
    app.key(dict.keys()[app.x])
    app.value1(dict.values()[app.x][0])
    app.value2(dict.values()[app.x][1])
    app.value3(dict.values()[app.x][2])   
    app.x +=1
```

I would like to avoid hard-coding, without `[0]`,`[1]`,`[2]`. If it is difficult to achieve with a dictionary, what data type should be use to get a desirable result? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: 1. Better store value1, value2, value3 as a list (tuple) and your problem is gone. 2. A perfect example why you shouldn't use class when you don't need it. Why do you even need a class, when you already have a dict?

Comment: 3. You are updating same `app` several times, overwriting it. Create an array of `app`s instead.

Comment: 4. Do you know that your app values are not updated, but merely printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to change your `App` class, but if you can't change it, then:

```
app = App(0)
funcs = [app.value1, app.value2, app.value3]
for i, (key, items) in enumerate(d.iteritems()):
    app.x = i
    app.key(key)
    for func, item in zip(funcs, items):
        func(item)
```